# SQL Server 2008: How to select all rows where field has all capital letters?

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008

Here is what I was thinking, I know that in this field, the first word will always be at least 2 characters long.

```
Select *  
From Table!
where SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3) like '[A-Z]'
```

However, this is bringing back non capital letters any ideas?

Comment: Fairly certain that `like` is case-insensitive

Comment: Depends on the collation sequence. The default collation is case-insensitive, so that's the behaviour you'll get unless the SQL Server, database, or column was defined with a case-sensitive collation. To ensure case-sensitivity, specify a case-sensitive collation: `...where not <some-column> like '%[^A-Z]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. All the usual caveats regarding collation sequence interactions apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where Name Not Like '%[^A-Z]%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

It should be noted that this will also exclude numbers and characters outside A-Z. If you wanted non-Latin upper case characters included, you really need to use the `Upper` function along with a `Collate` predicate:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where Name = Upper(Name) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

---

**Test script:**

```
With TestData As
    (
    Select '012324' As Name
    Union All Select 'ABC'
    Union All Select 'abc'
    Union All Select 'aBc'
    Union All Select 'ABé'
    Union All Select 'ABÉ'
    )
Select *
From TestData
Where Name = UPPER(Name) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Results:

```
012324
ABC
ABÉ
```

Comment: @Jai - On my test data, both work according to their bounds. I.e., using Upper and a Collate predicate only returns titles that are all upper case.

Comment: @Jai - I've posted a test script to illustrate.

Comment: @Jai - Btw, it should be noted that you do not have to choose the exact same collation I did here. It is that you need to choose a case-sensitive collation. In the naming the `CS` stands for case-sensitive. You can use the `fn_helpcollations` function to find the appropriate case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
x VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT #table1 SELECT '123aaa';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'foo';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'BaR';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'saM';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'Sam';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'SaM';
INSERT #table1 SELECT 'SAM';

SELECT * FROM #table1
WHERE CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), x) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), UPPER(x))

DROP TABLE #table1;
```

Output:

```
x
SAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to add a [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903.aspx) to your query.  [This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/) is a good example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about testing capitalized version against original:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UPPER(Name) = Name
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments this doesn't work if the collation is case-insensitive (which it is by default I think).  Check out Thomas's answer.

Comment: Won't help for the same reason the `LIKE` method didn't work: because of a case-insensitive collation that must probably be in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like

```
select * from Table!
where Name = upper(Name)
```